# Multiple Values selection in Drop DownList

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a `DropDownList` in which I have users as `dataText` and their ID's as `DataValue` fields.
I can select multiple users at a time, When I select a user I put his `email address`  in a label and `userID` in separate `Label`,`UserID label` is hidden.

In case of multiple users,email address label contains multiple email addresses,same as `userIDs label`,
I want to use a cross button for removing the `userEmail` from Label.
Can someone suggest how can I do this in alternate way?
This is how I am doing on `DropDown` Selected Index changed event

```
var userID = ddlclient.SelectedValue;
string email = AppUser.GetUserEmail(long.Parse(userID));
var prevemail = lblEmail.Text;
if (prevemail == "")
    lblEmail.Text = email;
else
    lblEmail.Text = prevemail + "," + email;

var prevId = lblUserID.Text;
if (prevId == "")
    lblUserID.Text = userID;
 else
    lblUserID.Text = prevId + "," + userID;
```

Comment: you could use a ListBox instead

Comment: @SubinJacob can you give some link?